# Почему камера в игре при сборке на андроид видит меньше,чем на ПК и в редакторе Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, unity3d-android, mobile-development

Игра на пк выглядит так[image: скрин с юнити]
Игра выглядит в сборке на андроид:

[image: гифка с телефона]

Суть в том,что на пк видно белые полосы по краям,и в игре прописано так,что машинка не едет дальше белых полос (на них не наезжает), на пк всё так и работает, но на телефоне она уезжает за края экрана и оттуда дальше не едет (так как полосы там всё же есть,но в камере их нет)
Разрешение, установленное в юнити, - 1920/1080
Разрешение телефона - 2340/1080 (Redmi Note 7)

Как сделать так,что бы на телефоне камера видела тоже самое,что и в редакторе юнити?

Comment: В этом вопросе не хватает вопроса.

Comment: Я думаю,что вполне очевидно то,что мне требуется сделать так,что бы камера на телефоне видела тоже самое,что и в редакторе,но ладно,я отредактирую вопрос

Comment: На картинке в редакторе выставлен display 1920x1080. Естественно, что игра на телефоне с другим соотношением сторон будет выглядеть по-другому. Следует добавить кода, подстраивающего видимую область.

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: Для канвас а никакого кода не нужно. Тупо настройка скейлера.

Comment: С канвасом проблем нет,нужно сделать так, чтобы на разных соотношениях сторон - камера видела одинаковую ширину,я не думаю,что игры на юнити делают под каждое разрешение,должна быть какая-то автоматическая (ну или полуавтоматическая) настройка на разные соотношения сторон

Comment: Нашёл скрипт для камеры от хорошего человека,который делает камеру нормальной
[вот ссылка на гитхаб](https://gist.github.com/Glavak/ada99b57023db3c941c5caebe42a70c5)